# receive SMS using python and python-smpp

Tags: python-3.x, smpp

I'm a newbie in SMPP but I need to simulate traffic over the SMPP protocol. I have found the tutorial how to send SMS using smpp lib from [Python How to Send SMS using SMPP Protocol](http://fosshelp.blogspot.com/2014/01/python-howto-send-sms-using-smpp.html)

I'm trying to write a receiver,but I am unable to get it to work. Please help.
My code is:

```
 import smpplib


class ClientCl():
    client=None
    def receive_SMS(self):
        client=smpplib.client.Client('localhost',1000)

        try:
            client.connect()          
            client.bind_receiver("sysID","login","password")
            sms=client.get_message()
            print(sms)

        except : 
            print("boom! nothing works")           
            pass


sms_getter=ClientCl.receive_SMS
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can understand the smpplib you are using is the one available at [github](https://github.com/podshumok/python-smpplib). Looking at your code and the client code, I can't find the function client.get_message. Perhaps you have an older version of the library? Or I have the wrong library. In any case, it is likely that the get_message function does not block and wait for the message to arrive.

Looking at the client code it seems that you have two options:

- Poll the library until you get a valid message
- Setup the library to listen to the SMPP port and call a function once a message arrives.

If you look at the [README.md](https://github.com/podshumok/python-smpplib/blob/master/README.md) file it shows how you can setup the library to implement the second option (which is the better option).

```
...
client = smpplib.client.Client('example.com', SOMEPORTNUMBER)

# Print when obtain message_id
client.set_message_sent_handler(
  lambda pdu: sys.stdout.write('sent {} {}\n'.format(pdu.sequence, pdu.message_id)))
client.set_message_received_handler(
  lambda pdu: sys.stdout.write('delivered {}\n'.format(pdu.receipted_message_id)))

client.connect()
client.bind_transceiver(system_id='login', password='secret')

for part in parts:
  pdu = client.send_message(
    source_addr_ton=smpplib.consts.SMPP_TON_INTL,
    #source_addr_npi=smpplib.consts.SMPP_NPI_ISDN,
    # Make sure it is a byte string, not unicode:
    source_addr='SENDERPHONENUM',

    dest_addr_ton=smpplib.consts.SMPP_TON_INTL,
    #dest_addr_npi=smpplib.consts.SMPP_NPI_ISDN,
    # Make sure thease two params are byte strings, not unicode:
    destination_addr='PHONENUMBER',
    short_message=part,

    data_coding=encoding_flag,
    esm_class=msg_type_flag,
    registered_delivery=True,
)
print(pdu.sequence)
client.listen()
...
```

When receiving a message or delivery receipt the function defined in client.set_message_received_handler() will be called. In the example, it is a lambda function. There is also an example on how to set up for listening in a thread.

If you prefer the simpler polling option you should use the `poll` function. For the simplest implementation all you need to do is:

```
while True:
  client.Poll()
```

As before, the function set in client.set_message_received_handler() will be called once a message arrives.